# What can I do about a missing row of tiles when preparing a floor for vinyl planks?

Tags: subfloor

I'm planning on putting vinyl plank flooring in my basement.  Right now I've  got the old asbestos tiles and want to leave them where they are at.  As you can see from the picture, one row was previously removed.

So I have to level this out.  Should I just put thinset down along the row?

[image]

Comment: Thinset mortar is not a pourable product, and if you were to over-water it to make it so you'd have a slurry with very little structural or bond integrity.

Comment: Voting to close as a product recommendation request. There are many skimcoat products available. Stop by your hardware/big box store and ask what they stock. I wouldn't mess with a self-leveling product. You may find that your floor is sloped in ways you hadn't anticipated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not pour anything there.  The chances are it will not be exactly level and may get on our under existing tiles.

I suggest you glue down some pure vinyl tiles right next to it with the same height.  Then when you lay your floor the pattern should be crossing the current pattern.  I would also suggest a good underlayment for you vinyl planks that should hide inconsistencies but the ability to use underlayment vary by manufacturer - but you can call them and even if it is outside their specs.